# Can we name python functions (not methods!) with leading underscores?

Tags: python, naming, pep8

According to PEP8 we should "use one leading underscore **only** for non-public **methods**" [of classes].

Can we use the same idea to distinguish **functions** (=not belonging to any class) inside modules (=files) between "public" functions called from outside the module and "non-public" functions called only from inside the module? Or is this not recommended? Not sure how strictly to interpret the guideline above.

//EDIT: Side question: If it is prohibited, is there another helpful syntax which can be used for that purpose?

Comment: Yes that same convention holds for: module-level variables, free functions, class methods, and class members

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Any reference?

Comment: Basically from PEP8 itself [Descriptive: Naming Styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) makes no distinction between class methods and free functions. They even give an example *The X11 library uses a leading X for all its public functions. In Python, this style is generally deemed unnecessary because attribute and method names are prefixed with an object, and function names are prefixed with a module name.* which are referring to module level free functions, and the same conventions apply

Comment: Ah perfect, somehow have overlooked this section: "_single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an underscore.". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to @CoryKramer for pointing out the [relevant section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)

> In addition, the following special forms using leading or trailing underscores are recognized [...]:
>
> - _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an underscore.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the answer.